# Are some apt long options undocumented?

Tags: apt, options, documentation

I cannot find documentation on some long, double-dash options of
apt, upon which I stumbled with Bash's tab-completion.

```
$ apt install --<TAB><TAB>
--allow-change-held-packages   --fix-broken                   --purge
--allow-downgrades             --fix-missing                  --reinstall
--allow-insecure-repositories  --fix-policy                   --remove
--allow-remove-essential       --force-yes                    --show-progress
--allow-unauthenticated        --ignore-hold                  --show-upgraded
--arch-only                    --ignore-missing               --simulate
--assume-no                    --install-recommends           --solver
--assume-yes                   --install-suggests             --target-release
--auto-remove                  --no-install-recommends        --trivial-only
--download                     --no-install-suggests          --upgrade
--download-only                --only-upgrade                 --verbose-versions
--dry-run                      --print-uris
```

I have looked in

```
apt --help
man apt
```

but they only provide brief information on the main apt arguments,
so I moved on to

```
man apt-get
man dpkg
```

where I found some of the long options, e.g.
`--simulate`, `--dry-run`, `--download-only`. But others seem to be lacking,
such as `--upgrade`, `--solver` and `--fix-policy`.

Is there some other manual page I am missing or
should the missing options be considered undocumented?

Comment: `--solver` could be related to https://packages.debian.org/unstable/apt-cudf possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `--fix-policy` is indeed not documented yet, see https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/master/debian/changelog https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=578020:

```
    - new "--fix-policy" option to install all packages with unmet
      important dependencies (useful with --install-recommends to
      see what not-installed recommends are on the system)
```

- Unfortunately I've been unable to find the documentation for `--solver` (which looks like an *internal* flag not meant to be used by the end user). From apt-private/private-cmndline.cc:

```
...
      addArg(0, "reinstall", "APT::Get::ReInstall", 0);
      addArg(0, "solver", "APT::Solver", CommandLine::HasArg);
      addArg(0, "planner", "APT::Planner", CommandLine::HasArg);
...
```

- There's no such option as `--upgrade` - looks like it's been deprecated.

You can always peruse apt sources to find out more: https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/tree/master/

Comment: It should be noted that [the people who write the Bourne Again shell's completions for `apt-get`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/graphs/contributors) are not the people who write the Bourne Again shell, nor are they [the people who write APT](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apt), who _are_ (just to confuse matters) the people who write the Bourne Again shell's completions for `apt`.  [Ville Skyttä last synchronized the `apt-get` completions against APT 1.5.1](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/commit/f4e54d918b5a367a7e665d563e2f8336553ea950).